# Swift 3.0 Annotation Dismiss Callout

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, viewdidappear

Is there a way to dismiss an annotation callout upon viewDidAppear? For instance, if I were to click on an annotation, the callout would appear. However, switching view controllers back to the mapView returns the annotation with the callout still there. I am interested in being able to dismiss the callout, but I know this requires manipulating annotationView and I am not sure how to incorporate this into viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code in your `viewDidAppear`

We cycle over the selected annotations and, call deselect on each one

```
    for annotation in self.mapView.selectedAnnotations
    {
        self.mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
```

Hope this helps